# regex for a street, city, zip code separated by commas

Tags: regex

i have a form field which needs `street, city, zip code` in the single field and i need to validate it with the `regex` and the javascript.

How can i do that? Please sent some regex which matches it.

I will be waiting for your precious answers.

Comment: oh, come on man, make a stab at it yourself. you can do it.

Comment: I dont think that this type of validation is possible with regex. And if it is then that is certainly not the best way to go because of constant changes in zips/addresses, etc..

Comment: what have you tried so far? (hint: `[a-z]` matches a letter and `[0-9]` matches a number)

Comment: You have to know what characters are legal in each field. I assume the street can't have a ',' - otherwise you'll need to specify the escaping or replacement character you use. Can your cities have apostrophies, hyphens, full stops, mixed case? "zip" code's some kind of U.S.A. thing...? I don't know the format. But very roughly "^[A-Za-z0-9-'.]+,[A-Za-z'.-],whatever-for-zip$"....  This is way short of adequate validation, but may catch a percentage of invalid inputs.

Comment: We can see right through your polite obfuscation.  You meant "gimme-teh-codez".  Are you sure it's the *street*?  It's much more common for the *state* to appear on the same line as city and zipcode.

Comment: can you provide some sample data

Answer (score 0):

`^(.+),([^,]+),([^,]+)$`
would do it.  But there are more efficient ways to split at commas than using regular expressions.

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+\,[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\,[0-9]{1,2,3}$ i have tried this one by myself but notworking so i need some advice

Comment: @Niroj: like @experimentX said, you need to give an example of the data that's not working before we can help you fix it.  But `[0-9]{1,2,3}` does not look correct.  `[0-9]{m,n}` would match *between* `m` and `n` digits -- it is a range, not a list.